# How to make a loop between a fixed date "hh:ss" and a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, hour

How to compare the date "hh:ss" cell Z4 with a range with the same format (AB4:AB19). It should take the cell Z4 and see if it is equal to any other cell in the range, if that is true, it should add two minutes and look again, and keep doing that until the value is no find in the range.

Whenever it finds a value that is not in the range it should place that value in the cell AB4. It should do it with all the values later (Z5,Z6... Z19). I add and image as an example that shows, already a value taht exists, and I need whenever I push the button "Grabar TOBT" to run that code individually.

[image]
    Sub CompTSAT1()

```
    Dim VALTSAT1 As Date
    VALSAT1 = Z4

    Do While VALSAT1 = Range("AB4:AB19")
        VALSAT1 = DateAdd(n, 2, VALSAT1)

        Exit Do

        AB4 = VALSAT1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot understand too much from your question and code, too... Please show us (at least) a picture with what you have and another one with what you need to accomplish.

Comment: It was edited to try to explain it clearer, thanks for the observartion.

Comment: So, in the searched cells there are Time values. What you present is only the format you can see them. Is that correct? I mean if `20:30` of yesterday data will not be equal with today `20:30`. Is that also correct?

Comment: Right, there are time values that a user will introduce , but they only will introduce the hour and minutes (e.g. 20:30) but, the idea is just to compare the hour, without taking into account the day.

Comment: So, it is not Time values. It is just a string. Is that assumption more correct? Can the same value be found more times in the range? I mean, it is not unique?

Comment: Being a string, 11:20:00 is different of 12:20. Is there any cell in discussion formatted as Time?

Comment: I thought that it was a date, but maybe it makes more sense to make it a string as you said. The idea is, that despite having the same value, in the column Z, in the column AB there wont be identical values, that is why I am trying to compare the value to the range, to, despite having the same value in Z, make the value in AB diffetent if it already exists

Comment: It may be time, too. But it is important for you to check. See what format is it, please...

Comment: Now it has the format date, because i want to show it has hh.mm, and the only way to add two minutes I found was to use the DateAdd formula

Comment: It always pop up the type mismatch error in this line Do While VALSAT1 = Range("AB4:AB19")

Comment: There it is a mistake. Let me try something and I will come back with a piece of code...

Answer (score 1):

At the end with some help in stackoverflow in spanish, I found the way of what I was looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GrabarTOBT()

Dim HorasOcupadas As Object: Set HorasOcupadas = CargaHorasOcupadas
Dim HoraStr As String
Dim HoraDeseada As Date
HoraDeseada = ActiveCell.Value
HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Dim HoraOcupada As Boolean: HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    Dim lrow: lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With

End Sub

Private Function CargaHorasOcupadas() As Object
Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    Dim lrow As Long: lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow > 3 Then
        Dim C As Range
        Dim Hora As String
        For Each C In .Range("AB4:AB" & lrow)
            Hora = Format(C, "hh:mm")
            Dict.Add Hora, 1
        Next C
    End If
End With
Set CargaHorasOcupadas = Dict

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code: When a value from column Z will be found in AB, the time with 2 minutes in plus will be calculated and you can se the original time versus the modified one. In order to do that, you have to press Ctrl + G. You can see the result in Immediate Window.

```
Sub testChangeTimeVal()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
    For i = 4 To sh.Range("Z" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 4 To sh.Range("Z" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If sh.Range("Z" & i).value = sh.Range("AB" & j).value Then
                Debug.Print Format(sh.Range("AB" & i).value, "hh:mm:ss"), _
                        Split(Format(sh.Range("AB" & i).value, "hh:mm:ss"), ":")(0) & ":" & _
                        CLng(Split(Format(sh.Range("AB" & i).value, "hh:mm:ss"), ":")(1)) + 2 & ":" & _
                        Split(Format(sh.Range("AB" & i).value, "hh:mm:ss"), ":")(2)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It keeps runs but doesn't find any result. The ides is to be able to run it individually for each cell of the column Z, because, the values will be introduced in different moments of time. That way, when a value is introduced, the code tests the value (by pressing a button or just by inserting it, i don't care) with the other values, this means that the fist value won't need to check with any value because the column AG is empty, but the second value whenever is introduced (It could be the next row in the column Z or not, it is no secuencial) should check with the values already placed.

Comment: What do you mean? Where do you look for the result? It iterates between all existing cells in column Z:Z and each such value is compared with all range AB:AB and both values matches `Debug.Print` returns the result in Immediate Window. Do you know what Immediate Window is and how to open it? I gave you clear instructions above... But, now I understood that you do not need to iterate once for ever between the existing values of Z:Z column. If you will do that, the initial values in column AB:AB will be modified at the previous ran. Maybe you would want only the last cell to be checked.

Comment: And put the code in Worksheet_Change event, targeting column Z:Z...

Comment: I am looking for the result in the column AB of the worksheet, where the values should be shown, after not finding it already in the column. No inmediate windows appears, despite having it open VBA.

Comment: And yeah, I do not want to be checked one, I want to be able to run it whenever i introduce a new value just for the last value introduced. To give you a backgorund, it is a way of sequencing departures, if the tyime you want the departure (column Z) is taken already (someone wrote it firts) the next departure within 2 minutes will be yours (column AG)

Comment: Then, you firstly must learn asking a question... Secondly, I never make a code able to mess up your data, if the result is not what you want. In order to see the Immediate Window, you must be in IDE. How do you run your code? Where did you pasted the code? Please, press Alt + F11 and go in VBE. Then THERE, pres Ctrl + G and you will see the Immediate window and the code return. Please do that now and confirm that you handled it. We will make the next step only after that...

Comment: Yeah, I know you are trying to help and i really appreciate it, sincerely. I was in IDE VBE was opened all the time and the code pasted in the upper part (general), and the inmmediate window also, but no result appeared when it was runned.

Comment: So, is your active sheet the one with your data to be processed? If yes, stay in VBE click somewhere inside the code and press F8. In this way you will run the code line by line. You can see if the code reach the line with `Debug.Print` and the returned value... Do you have TeamViewer installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes it is the active sheet, but when I run the codeno value is returned, I do not have the team viewer, and because of lack of permits I am unable to install it (I tried). Maybe my mistake is where I am pasting the code. I pasted it in the VBE worksheet with the data, but, Is that the way of pasting it in Worksheet_Change event?, and must I do something to target the column Z:Z?, It is implicit in the code, right?

Comment: It is good to insert a module and paste the code in that module. Do you know how to insert a module? But, it should work in sheet module, too. Are you sure that you know what Immediate Window is? Please create a nes sub and put only `Debug.Print "Test"`. Do you see it in Immediate Window?

Comment: Do you still have problems with the code? If yes, try to make a similar workbook when you are at home and give me your TeamViewer ID and password. I will show you hou to be used and is a problem in your file, how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Try the code bellow:

```
Sub CheckTSAT()

Dim lastRowIndex As Long
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim tobtRange As Range
Dim tsatRange As Range
Dim tobt As Range
Dim tobtTime As Single
Dim i As Long

'//Supose that you sheet is named 'Data'
Set wsData = Sheets("Data")

'//Get ranges
Set tobtRange = wsData.Range("Z4:Z" & wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
Set tsatRange = wsData.Range("AB4:AB" & wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)

'//Looping through all filled cells in the columns TBOT manual
For Each tobt In tobtRange

    '//Get week number from cell in column "AM"
    tobtTime = tobt.Value
    teste = Format(tobtTime, "hh:mm:ss")

    '//Count TOBT time in the TSAT range
    checkTobtTimeInTsat = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf( _
    tsatRange, Format(tobtTime, "hh:mm:ss"))

    '//Check if the TOBT time exist in TSAT range
    If checkTobtTimeInTsat > 0 Then

        '//Add 2 minutes to the TOBT time
        tobtTime = DateAdd("n", 2, tobtTime)
    Else
        '//Shifts the range AB4 down
        wsData.Range("AB4").Insert Shift:=xlDown

        '//Put the updated TOBT time in cell AB4
        wsData.Range("AB4").Value = Format(tobtTime, "hh:mm:ss")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It is almost working, thanks. You will see in the next image that values are writtent but, it is like it crossed the values (https://imgur.com/a/2grYyEZ) I associate the macro to the "Botón 25". Just to complete the code, I will like to have it done individually, which means, that I will associate one "Botón" to each TOBT manual (column Z), and it will seek just that time on TSAT (If I have already pushed that "Botón" before for another TOBT manual (column Z), that TSAT (column AB) shouldnt be affected, until I push it again that I will seek the new TOBT manual (column Z) again. We are close